# CSS Clear not working if parent has height: 0

Tags: html, css

I've come across a strange CSS issue.  Below is my html

```
<div id="contact-me-content">

    <form action="" method="post">

        <label for="contact-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your name" />

        <input type="submit" style="float:right" name="contact-submit" id="contact-submit" value="Send" />
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Below is the css

```
#contact-me-content
{
height: 0;
padding: 5px;
background: #ffffff;
border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

I am floating the submit button right and then trying to clear the float so that the form is contained in the parent div.  Because the parent div has height:0 the clear isn't working.  However if I remove the height: 0 it works fine.  Does anyone know a way round this or can give me a explanation?

Thanks

Comment: the form container will always have some height because of the form, so why do you need the `height: 0` ?

Comment: @Pattle Why exactly do you think that clearing does not work here?

Comment: @ZoltanToth I need height 0 because I want to hide the div when the page loads but I could do it another way

Comment: @MaratTanalin The clearing is not working because the white background of the parent div does not encompass the form

Comment: @Pattle Zero height specified is why visible (having white background) area of the container has zero height. Clearing _does_ work. If you want background to contain blocks contents, remove `height: 0`. Or move background from container to the contained form. BTW, why do you need `height: 0` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make work you should try to add `display: inline-block;` in `#contact-me-content` then only your floated element can have `clear: both;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `height: 0` to hide the div you could use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.  If you must use `height: 0`, then also add `overflow: hidden` to the container and any part of the form that overflows will be hidden.  Note that the padding gives it some visibility, so you can either set that to 0 and add it back later, or add padding to the form element instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/BQCqJ/